# d3.js force directed interactive coloring for groups

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working from [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) of a D3.js force-directed graph. The example colors the nodes according to their group membership for one set of groups. I have this working fine with my data. However, my data can be grouped on multiple node attributes (e.g. by gender or by party affiliation). The simple solution is to simply make separate graphs, each colored according to a different attribute.

Is there a way to have the color scheme be interactive (rather than hard coded)? Will D3 let me add a drop down or button to pick which attribute (gender, affiliation...) is used to color the nodes? [This code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334704/adding-and-removing-nodes-and-links-from-force-diagram-in-d3-based-on-filter-dro) lets a user interactively filter their data using a drop down menu, but I'm not sure how I might go from that to interactively picking attributes to use for colors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to

1. build some colour scales and functions for the attributes you'd want to colour on
2. use them to generate a select element with appropriate options
3. then call a small routine that recolours the nodes

https://jsfiddle.net/vbpqn1e6/

This is the miserables example with such stuff, it could be tidied up a bit / a lot but shows the principle:

```
var groupColor = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
var nameColor = d3.scaleLinear().domain([65,78,90]).range(["#f00", "#0f0", "#00f"]);
var madameColor = d3.scaleLinear().domain([true, false]).range(["#f00", "#aaa"]);

var colFuncs = {
    "Group": function (d) { return groupColor (d.group); },
    "Name": function (d) { return nameColor (d.id.substring(0,1).toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0)); },
    "Madame?": function(d) { return madameColor (d.id.substring(0,2) === "Mm"); }
};
var currentColFunc = colFuncs["Group"];

d3.select("body").insert("select", ":first-child")
  .on ("change", function() {
      var e = d3.event;
      if (e) {
        currentColFunc = colFuncs[e.target.value];
        updateColour();
      }
  })
    .selectAll("option")
    .data(d3.keys(colFuncs))
  .enter()
  .append("option")
  .attr("value", function(d) { return d; })
  .text (function(d) { return d; })
 ;
```

The `.on("change")` event listens to the select element and when an option is chosen uses that option's value to set the current Colour scheme (`currentColFunc`). If you want more choices just add more to the `colFuncs` object.

This is then used in updateColour:

```
   function updateColour () {
    node.attr("fill", function(d) { 
        return currentColFunc(d); 
    });
   }
```

Comment: This is great, but it breaks my legend code. How would I get a legend to update when the color scheme does? `var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend").data(currentColFunc.domain())` isn't working (for obvious reasons).